# Referring shared Java EE library for EAR application in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I have created a shared library with some jar files in weblogic server, now I have an EAR application and I want to use the class files from shared library in my web applications present in EAR application. So I have created `weblogic-application.xml` file inside my `ear-app/META-INF/` directory and gave reference to shared library using below tags:

```
<library-ref>
    <library-name>ebs_endeca_artifacts</library-name>
</library-ref>
```

But when I am trying to access the class files in my application, I am getting exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Also it is required for me to refer to the shared library at ear level instead of declaring in `weblogic.xml` file of individual war files.

If I directly place the same jar files in my `ear-app/APP-INF/lib` directory instead of using shared library then my application is working fine without any issues.

Please help me how can I use the shared library in my ear application. I am using `weblogic server 10.3.6`

My shared library structure will be like this:

```
shared-web-app/WEB-INF/web.xml
shared-web-app/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the jars from the shared library in your classpath, because before you deploy the `EAR`, the application needs to be built. JDeveloper wouldn't know where are those classes stored, so that it need those at `compile-time`.

When preparing the application for deployment, you can create filters for the files that can be added within the `WAR`/`EAR`/`<whatever>`. Go to `Application Properties` -> `Deployment` and select your deployment profile. Click on the `Edit` button and a screen will be prompted, from where you can filter the files/libraries that can be included when the application is built.

If you don't include the shared library in the archive and have the fragment from the `weblogic-application.xml` you've posted, the WebLogic server will then use the classes from the shared library.

Hope that helps. Ask anything you don't understand as a comment. :)

Comment: Thanks kocko, The EAR and shared-library both are deployed in weblogic successfully. But I am facing problem when I try to access any web applications from browser which are part of my EAR. Also I have updated my post with the details about shared library.

Comment: So, as I understand, your shared library is a web-application, not a jar ?

Comment: I don't understand why do you need it as a shared library, when it's a web application ? Or it exposes some REST-services ?

Comment: I want all the jar files to be combined as a single library, so created it like that, please let me know if there is an alternate way of doing it.

Comment: The shared-library should NOT be web-application. :)

Comment: Can you please suggest how to do in my scenario?

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/deploying-adf-applications-as-shared.html

Comment: @chaitanya.. I am doing similar sort of deployment, where i packaged all my jars and its dependencies in a war file and deployed that war file as a shared library. Now my other ear modules are referring to this war in the weblogic-appliation.xml. But i am getting NoClassDefFound Error. My weblogic version is 12c. Please advice.